# Set just a couple of parameters in a Struct

Tags: solidity, remix, struct

I have a struct with 10 parameters. The idea is to apply this struct for represent the flow of a trace. So I have to set variables values in a stepped way. Now i´m trying to call a function to set the first three values, but the compiler gives me a error.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

import "browser/DateTime.sol";

contract Travel {

address private owner;

struct TravelStruct 
{
    //Origin
    address clientAddress;
    string originAirportName;
    uint32 originTime; //In timestamp
    uint16 originBagWeight;
    //Tape
    uint32 tapeArrivedTime; //In timestamp
    //Plane
    bytes8 flyCode;
    uint32 takeOffTime; //In timestamp
    //Destiny
    string destinationAirportName;
    uint32 destinyTime; //In timestamp
    uint16 destinyBagWeight;
}

mapping(uint => Travel) travels;
uint public travelsRegistryCount;

constructor() public
{
    owner = msg.sender;
    travelsRegistryCount = 1;
}

modifier ownerFunc 
{
    require(owner == msg.sender);
    _;
}


function setOrigin (string _originAirportName, uint32 _originTime, uint16 _originBagWeight) private
{
    travels[travelsRegistryCount] = TravelStruct(owner, _originAirportName, _originTime, _originBagWeight, 0, "", 0, "", 0, 0);
}  
}
```

> browser/Travel.sol:45:41: TypeError: Type struct Travel.TravelStruct memory is not implicitly convertible to expected type contract Travel.
>           travels[travelsRegistryCount] = TravelStruct(owner, _originAirportName, _originTime, _originBagWeight, 0, "", 0, "", 0, 0);
>                                           ^----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------^

First I try to set the first trhee values of the struct but the IDE tell me that the struct have more parameter than the three parameters that I load. So I put the trhee real values and the other 7 fake values. But the problem persist and now is telling my the block quote message.

- How can I solve this??
- It´s posible to load just the values that I want(something like: travels[travelsRegistryCount] = TravelStruct(owner, _originAirportName, _originTime, _originBagWeight)??
- And for a traceability project is the correct way to make all the values in the same struct or is a better practice to make this cain of flow??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Travel is contract name.

change mapping to

mapping(uint => TravelStruct) travels;

you can load values like

```
travels[travelsRegistryCount].clientAddress
travels[travelsRegistryCount].originAirportName
```

> And for a traceability project is the correct way to make all the
>   values in the same struct or is a better practice to make this cain of
>   flow??

It is the correct way. Of course, needs more implementation :)

Comment: Thats true and solved the problem ;D. But can you help me with the ither questions??

Comment: @Eduardo, I modified  :)

Comment: Thx for help men ;D

Comment: I can´t be able to look at traceability information so im doing a lot of ussefull and stupid things jejej. But day a day im understanding more in deep blockchain/ethereum world

Comment: I'm studying blockchain/ethereum too. hehe

Comment: We are explores of new technologies !! ;D